# Fstream read function does not write data into indicated address

Tags: c++, fstream

My problem is concerning the following code:

```
void znajdzNastepnyElement(fstream& baza, unsigned int& licz_zaglebienie, unsigned long long int& kursor, unsigned long long int& poczatek_elementu, const unsigned int& dl_baza) {
    char znak = '\0';
    if (kursor <= dl_baza) {
        while (znak != '{' && kursor <= dl_baza) {
            baza.seekg((kursor) * sizeof(char), ios::beg);
            baza.read(&znak, sizeof(char));
            cout << endl << "Znak =" << znak << "Kursor = " << kursor << endl;
            if (znak == '{') {
                licz_zaglebienie++;
                poczatek_elementu = kursor;
            }
            if (znak == '}')
                licz_zaglebienie--;
        kursor++;
        }
        cout << "Szukam elementu" << endl;
    }
}
```

It is basically meant to find the following "{" character in the json file (which is full of these curly braces). Debugging that function showed, that only the first time, when program performs it results in saving "{" into &znak, since then nothing but "\0" (that actually depends on what I save into 'znak' in line `char znak = '\0';`) replaces that value. What's even more confusing is that it only happens when the first character in json file is "{", every next matching character does not have such influence on program. To be clear, "{" occurence does not result in "fstream close" in any form outside of the function.

Comment: You are not checking `baza.seekg()` or `baza.read()` for failure before interpreting the output

Comment: How can I do it? Using goodbit?

Comment: You are also failing to provide a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste, compile, and run with simple instructions, in order to reproduce your observed results.

Comment: @drydre Yes. `if (!baza.seekg(...)) { failed }` ... `if (!baza.read(...)) { failed }`